# How do I send 1 item to the end while the rest are centered in a flexbox container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Using a flexbox container, how can I have the first child centered and the second child at the end? I tried the following but it didn't work:

```css
.flexbox {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 200px;
}

.box1 {
  width: 100px;
}

.box2 {
  width: 100px;
  justify-self: end; /* does nothing */
}

div{ border: 1px solid black; } /* to help see the divs */
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
  <div class="box1"></div>
  <div class="box2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`Justify-self` only works with `grid` not `flexbox`

```css
.flexbox {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  height: 200px;
  width: 500px;
  background: orange;
}

.box1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px; 
  background: red;
  justify-self: end;
}

.box2 {
  width: 100px;
  justify-self: end;
  height: 200px; 
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
  <div class="box1"></div>
  <div class="box2"></div>
</div>
```

For your problem though, you can solve it using `absolute` positioning

```css
.flexbox {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 200px;
  width: 500px;
  background: orange;
}

.box1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
}

.box2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  background: blue;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
  <div class="box1"></div>
  <div class="box2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make a first box that's invisible and then using flex: space-between. Here's how I did it.

```css
.flexbox {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 200px;
}

.flexbox-again {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  height: 200px;
}

.box0 {
  width: 100px;
  background: none;
}

.box1 {
  width: 100px;
  background: blue;
}

.box2 {
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  justify-self: end; // does nothing
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
  <div class="box0"></div>
  <div class="box1"></div>
  <div class="box2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use align-self property. It will work**

```
.box2 {
     width: 100px;
     align-self: flex-end;
}
```

Comment: I tested this and it didn't work... though I'm sure that `align-self` is for the axis perpendicular to the flex-direction so I didn't expect it to work.

Answer (score -1):

You can do center the first element using `margin-left: 50%;` and right align the second element using `margin-right: 0;` Remove `justify-contect: center` from your main div.

```css
.flexbox { 
    display: flex; 
    height: 200px;
    background: yellow;
}
.box1 { 
  width: 100px; 
  margin-left: 50%;
  background: blue;
}
.box2 { 
    width: 100px; 
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: 0;
    background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
    <div class="box1">fdgdfg</div>
    <div class="box2">dfgdg</div>
</div>
```